# iOS - Weird navigation problem?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller

I have 3 UIViewControllers in my UINavigationController.
At some points I want to go to rootViewController and from there navigate to a new UIViewController, and it doesn't aeem to work.

Any suggestions?

```
- (IBAction)goToRootAndNavigateToViewController
{
   [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

   MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
   [mvc release];

   //This takes me to the rootViewController but it doesn't navigate to MyViewController
}
```

Trying to use performSelector:WithDelay:

```
- (void)goToRootAndNavigateToViewController
{
    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    [self performSelector:@selector(doSomething) withObject:nil afterDelay:10];
}

- (void)doSomething
{
    MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
    [mvc release];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the popToRootViewController takes up the full NSRunLoop.

You would need to push your next view controller with a separate function using something like `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay`.

or you could always just do a `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:]` call to set them manually

Comment: Adding a delay is hacky, and setting ViewController doesn't work for me either because I need to keep my root viewcontroller

Comment: setting a delay isnt hacky.  those methods are put into the sdk for a reason - to do things like this inside the NSRunLoop.  set the delay interval to 0.0 if you want.  and setting the view controllers while keeping the root view controller shouldnt be a problem either.  just save a reference to your root view controller and have that as the first element in the NSArray you pass to `setViewControllers:animated` and you will still have it as the root

Comment: I tried the delay it didn't work, I tried setting the delay to 15 seconds and it still didn't work

Comment: can you paste your code sample of how you are doing the delay and/or setViewControllers:animated

Comment: i see now.  I think we were miscommunicating.  using the `performSelector:withObject:afterDelay` won't work in this case, because when you `popToRootViewController` control of your app leaves the current view controller and is taken over by the root view controller.  Your best best is probably to use the `[self.navigationController setViewControllers:]` method

Answer (score 0):

You need to push your `mvc` controller when the animation is complete. Try calling it once the first animation is done (e.g. in `- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated`)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you are facing this problem, but one solution you could try is to push the new view controller in your root view controller's `-viewDidAppear:` method.

Answer (score 0):

I guess it has to do with your current viewcontroller using `- (IBAction)goToRootAndNavigateToViewController`, is somehow losing its control once being popped. Thus, making consecutive statements to be not working.

If I were you, I would make sure pushing `MyViewController` instance is done always at `rootViewController` of your choice, not from the current viewcontroller which is going to be popped from `UINavigationController` **and possibly to be released and deallocated**.

Probably, you may want to add delegate method implementation for, such as `- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated` in your `rootViewController`

```
- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController animated:(BOOL)animated {
    // Check the right condition for pushing MyViewController...
    // if it's YES...
    MyViewController *mvc = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:mvc animated:YES];
   [mvc release];
}
```

In this implementation, you may push `MyViewController` instance. One thing you have to do beforehand is using some kind of conditional flag, which will make sure the situation is correct for `popToRootViewController` then push `MyViewController`